# Exit Code when called with No Arguments

Tags: bash, exit-code

I have a script that requires at least one argument. If the arguments are incorrect I will obviously return a non-zero exit code.

I have decided to print the *usage instructions* when called with no arguments, but I'm uncertain of the *exit code*. Should it be

- `0` (success)
- one of the values [1-125] (error)

An argument could be made either way. Is some option recommended?

Comment: This question is very subjective, there is no right answer — it's entirely up to the author.

Comment: Also your question title is meaning different than the actual content, _wrong_ arguments and _empty_ arguments are _not_ one and the same

Comment: @inian, oops. fixed.

Comment: @I'L'I I was hoping this would not be entirely subjective.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on whether you want the callers of your script to know programatically *why* it failed.

If, for example, it will only ever be run by a human, you could just return `1` and rely on the error text to inform them.

You *could* even return zero regardless if you only ever want a human to easily know (via the output) if it failed but I would consider this very bad form - Microsoft have made this mistake in the past with some of their commands not setting `%errorlevel%`, making it *very* difficult for a script to figure out whether it's worked or not.

Even if you decide not to indicate why it failed, you should at least indicate *that* it failed.

If you want a *program* to easily figure out *why* it failed, return a different code for each discernible error type.

Answer (score 2):

Any Unix command when it returns control to its parent process returns a code, number between 0 and 255.

*Success* is traditionally represented with `exit 0`; *failure* is normally indicated with a non-zero exit-code. This value can indicate different reasons for failure.

So what you have also is another case of unsuccessful completion of your program which should be treated as returning a proper error code and *not* 0.

Also note that traditional Unix system calls don't signal an error code for empty arguments, they have to be caught explicitly. There are ones for argument list too long (`E2BIG`) and invalid arguments (`EINVAL`).

Answer (score 1):

This is what I decided on using, based mostly on [Inians answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50405954/1119345) and the reserved exit codes presented [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html).

I decided on somewhat reusing the exit codes defined in `/usr/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h`<sup>1</sup>. There was nothing suitable for "too little arguments", so I picked the first one from the 64-113 range.

```
# Error codes
E2BIG=7
EINVAL=22
E2SMALL=64

NAME="my-script"
USAGE=$(cat << END
    the help text
RETURN CODES
    $NAME has the following return codes:

    0   success
    $E2BIG  Argument list too long
    $EINVAL Invalid argument
    $E2SMALL    Argument list too short
END
)

# This script requires exactly one argument. If less are provided it prints
# the USAGE instructions
if [ ${#} -lt 1 ] ; then
    printf '%s\n' "${USAGE}"
    exit $E2SMALL
fi
if [ "${1}" = "-h" ] || [ "${1}" = "--help" ] ; then
    printf '%s\n' "${USAGE}"
    exit 0
fi
if [ ${#} -gt 1 ] ; then
    printf '%s\n' "${USAGE}"
    exit $E2BIG
fi
```

It's a bit verbose, but at least there's a properly defined error code if the script is called improperly.

---

<sup>1</sup> This may be debatable, but since the codes were already defined...